# Run inference on Arm NN android with onnx model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, onnx

Can any one tell me how can we run inference on Arm NN android with onnx model. On armnn site i have searched for this but there is not enough content for onnx model for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/JDAI-CV/DNNLibrary that provides Android NNAPI access from ONNX.

we can try using the armnnOnnxParser but be warned it is at a fairly early stage of development and may not support the layers in your model. You can check https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn/blob/master/src/armnnOnnxParser/OnnxSupport.md to see if the layers in your model are supported.